# Apply directive from component to child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

In Vue.js, if I have a component, such as `custom-input`, and I want to set focus from the parent class, can a directive from the parent be applied to the child?

```
<custom-input v-focus />

<div class='form-group'>
  <input :v-focus='vFocus'> // This doesn't work
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  Vue.directive("focus", {
    inserted: function(el) {
      el.focus();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible out of box. There's a bit of magic behind the scenes that the template renderer does, that doesn't support this functionality. You could implement the functionality using the render function, but that could get quite complex.

The easier solution is to implement it by updating the component template and the directive.

here is a simple example http://jsfiddle.net/7tzLgp1c/

```
Vue.directive("focus", {
  inserted: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    if (binding.value !== undefined && binding.value !== false)
      el.focus();
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    foo: {
      props: {
        focus: {
          default: undefined,
        }
      },
      template: '<div><input v-focus="focus"></div>'
    }
  }
})
```

template

```
<div id="app">
  <foo focus></foo>
  <foo></foo>
</div>
```

the trick here is to implement a condition inside the directive, since the directive `inserted` function runs on all components that have the directive. then instead of using the directive on the parent, you would pass it down

Comment: That's what I had assumed, but I couldn't even find someone asking this. Is there a reason you are excluding `undefined`? It makes `v-focus` without a value not work.

Comment: I used undefined and false, because it allows not setting at all (undefined) and explicitly setting to false. this allows using `<foo focus/>` and `<foo :focus="true"/>` which I see as the two main use cases. It is however meant as an example only, and you should make changes to suit your needs